# How difficult would it be to replace these fuses with circuit breakers?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, replacement, 240v

I had a fuse blow last night. While the short-term plan is just to replace the fuse wire, in the longer term I'd like to switch them out for circuit breakers for the added safety but mostly for the convenience.

[image: consumer unit][image: business end of one of the fuses][image: fuse's previous home]
<sub>*Click for larger view*</sub>

Is this going to be a simple case of swapping the fuses for circuit breaker units or will I need a new consumer unit? If it is a simple swap, is there anything I need to bear in mind when buying the breakers (beyond the obvious matching of current ratings)?

I'm not sure if it's relevant, and the voltage might have already given it away, but I'm in the UK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can get pop in breaker replacements.

They look something like this:  [image]

The important thing is to ensure that you use a breaker that is the same ampage as your fuse (or very close to).  When I did mine (before rewiring the house) I had some fuse wire that was something like 15A.  But the closest breaker was 16A.  That's usually ok because the wiring is actually rated higher than that.  But for safety make it as close as you can.

[Breakers on ebay in UK...](http://www.ebay.com/itm/WYLEX-15A-RE-WIRE-FUSE-REPLACEMENT-MCB-CIRCUIT-BREAKER-REPLACES-REWIRE-FUSE-NEW-/251287015011?pt=UK_BOI_CircuitBreakers_RL&hash=item3a81df8e63)